# How can I set up a simple CGAL + Qt program

Tags: c++, qt4, cgal

I would like to set up a simple CGAL + Qt program. In a nutshell, I would like to take the following:

https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Arrangement_on_surface_2/examples/Arrangement_on_surface_2/conics.cpp

and print out a visualization of it using Qt. I have no problems compiling the above:

```
cgal_create_CMakeLists -c Core
cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/usr/share/CGAL/ .
make
```

and have been able to compile various Qt programs using qmake, but I'm having a hard time using Qt inside the conics.cpp file.

My questions are:

- what Qt libraries do I need to include
- how do I use the inserter to insert arr into the Qt widget stream
- how do I set up and run using cmake

**UPDATE**

I've been trying to figure out how to compile a program with Qt headers. Following the Polygon demo, I added:

```
// Qt headers
#include <QtGui>
#include <QString>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QInputDialog> 
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>
```

to conics.cpp. I had no luck with either:

```
cgal_create_cmake_script
```

or:

```
cgal_create_CMakeLists -c Core:Qt5
```

what is working so far is to modify the CMakeLists.txt found in the Polygon demo as so:

```
project (Qt_Demo)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
if(NOT POLICY CMP0070 AND POLICY CMP0053)
  # Only set CMP0053 to OLD with CMake<3.10, otherwise there is a warning.
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 OLD)
endif()

find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Qt5 Core)

include(${CGAL_USE_FILE})

find_package(Qt5 QUIET COMPONENTS Xml Script OpenGL Svg)

include_directories (BEFORE ../../include)

if ( CGAL_FOUND AND CGAL_Qt5_FOUND AND Qt5_FOUND )

  add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

  if( CGAL_Core_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DCGAL_USE_CORE)
  endif()

  #--------------------------------
  # Demo: Polygon_2
  #--------------------------------
  # UI files (Qt Designer files)
  #qt5_wrap_ui( DT_UI_FILES Polygon_2.ui )

  # qrc files (resources files, that contain icons, at least)
  #qt5_add_resources ( CGAL_Qt5_RESOURCE_FILES ./Polygon_2.qrc )

  # use the Qt MOC preprocessor on classes that derives from QObject
  qt5_generate_moc( conics.cpp "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conics.moc" )

#  add_library( CGAL SHARED IMPORTED )
#  SET_PROPERTY(TARGET CGAL PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CGAL_LIBRARY} )

  # The executable itself.
  add_executable  ( conics conics.cpp conics.moc ${DT_UI_FILES} ${DT_RESOURCE_FILES} ${CGAL_Qt5_RESOURCE_FILES} ${CGAL_Qt5_MOC_FILES} )

  qt5_use_modules(conics Xml Script OpenGL Svg)

  add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS conics )


  # Link with Qt libraries
  target_link_libraries( conics ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
  # And with CGAL libraries
  target_link_libraries( conics ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )

else()

  message(STATUS "NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL, CGAL_Core, and Qt5, and will not be compiled.")

endif()
```

Really, there should be a simpler approach!

Answer (score 1):

- "What Qt libraries do I need to include?"
  You need the following libraries from Qt

```cpp
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
```

In addition to those, you'll need some CGAL::Qt libraries to support CGAL data structures

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Qt/GraphicsViewNavigation.h>
```

You'll also need a custom graphics item to represent Arrangement_2
instead of `QGraphicsLineItem`.

An Arrangement_2 item in CGAL is represented by combination of Vertices, Edges and Faces. Hence, you need a custom QGraphicsItem for displaying Arrangement_2 on to a scene in Qt.

In [CGAL Demo](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/tree/master/Arrangement_on_surface_2/demo/Arrangement_on_surface_2), you can find a predefined graphics item in Arrangement_2GraphicsItem.h which can be used to display arr of conics.

- How do I use the inserter to insert arr into the Qt widget stream?

Once you have a `Arrangement_2GraphicsItem`, you can pass the reference to arr into the graphics item and add the graphics item to the Qt scene.

```cpp
arr_gi = new CGAL::Qt::ArrangementGraphicsItem<Arrangement_2>(&arr);
scene.addItem(arr_gi);
```

- How do I set up and run using CMake?

Your CMakeLists.txt should look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project(conics)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread system REQUIRED)
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Qt5)
find_package(Qt5 QUIET COMPONENTS Qt5 Core)


# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (conics
conics.cpp
ArrangementGraphicsItem.h
ArrangementPainterOstream.h #ArrangementGraphicsItem dependencies
ArrangementTypes.h
Utils.h
${CGAL_Qt5_RESOURCE_FILES} ${CGAL_Qt5_MOC_FILES})

qt5_use_modules(conics Xml Script OpenGL Svg)


include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(conics CGAL::CGAL_Core CGAL::CGAL CGAL::CGAL_Qt5 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I tried to do what you described here and got an error from `cmake`: `-- libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies:  <CGAL/Qt/*.h> headers cannot be configured.` CGAL version - 5.0 (on ubuntu 18.04.3). What might be a problem?

Comment: The above example was written for CGAL 4.14. The new CGAL 5.0, is offered as a "header-only" library by default. Assuming you have all the [required Qt5 components](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/thirdparty.html#thirdpartyQt) installed, I suspect that your issue might have something to do with this. I recommend you check out the [manual installation page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html) on the CGAL manual, and perhaps ask a question on here with more information about your issue.

Comment: Everything has been installed correctly, and I was able to build and run a simple CGAL+Qt5 example using `make`. However, it's a pain to use `make` with Qt because of their `moc` - so I wanted to try `cmake`, which seems to support the `moc`. Sorry to say, I've got stuck on the `<CGAL/Qt/*.h>` problem